# java 8 lambdas interface mismatch

Tags: java, lambda

I have an interface with following code

```
public interface DoSomething {
    public void blah(String s);
}
```

Next, i have a class which uses this interface as shown below

```
public class Dummy {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    //how is the below working when String's equalsIgnoreCase method signature does not match the signature of my interface DoSomething
    String s = "Jim";
    doSomething(s::equalsIgnoreCase, "jim");
  //Again signature mismatch, but code compiles fine
    doSomething(String::toUpperCase, "jim");

 }
 public static void doSomething(DoSomething x, String s) {
    x.blah(s);
 }
}
```

Comment: What part of the method signatures do you think don't match? The return type?

Comment: [I have run your program](https://ideone.com/8rbXAT) and works ok. Please add your log.

Comment: He is wondering why it works, not why it not works.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think the OP is asking why he can pass `s::equalsIgnoreCase` or `String::toUpperCase` as the first parameter to `doSomething`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Right. Why do they think they shouldn't be able to?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis my interface returns void, where as string's equalIgnoreCase returns a boolean and toUpperCase returns a String

Comment: That's what I thought. See the duplicate.